# Printing 2D array in full ignores edited values, prints initialised values

Tags: c++, arrays

beginner to C++ and attempting a dungeon crawler beginner task, upon testing one of the classes I found that printing the 2D array works, however if it is edited and printed, it resets and prints original values it was initialised with.

InitGrid is used to initialize the array.

```
class MAP
{
public:
/*
Difficulty used in number of enemies and traps created.
1-5 Difficulty
| 1 - Too easy | 2 - Easy | 3 - Normal | 4 - Hard | 5 - Insane |
*/
int Difficulty = Hard; //### Temporary, user selection needs implemented ###

int SpawnPos;
int TPosX; //Treasure Postion, used to checkwinstate.
int TPosY; //Treasure Postion, used to checkwinstate.

char Grid[MAPHeight][MAPWidth];

void InitGrid()
{
    for (int y = 0; y < 9; y++)    //Row loop
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 14; x++) //Column loop
        {
            Grid[y][x] = { '.' };
        }
    }
}

void PrintMap()
{
    for (int y = 0; y < 9; y++)    //This loops on the rows.
    {
        for (int PrintX = 0; PrintX < 14; PrintX++) //This loops on the columns
        {
            cout << Grid[y][PrintX] << "  ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void GenerateEnemies()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Difficulty; i++)
    {
        int TotEnemies = (Difficulty * 1.5);

        for (TotEnemies; TotEnemies == 0; TotEnemies--)
        {
            int x = rand() % (MAPWidth - 1);
            int y = rand() % (MAPHeight - 1);

            if (Grid[y][x] == '.')
            {
                Grid[y][x] = '#';
            }
            else
            {
                GenerateEnemies();
            }
        }
    }
}

// Generate Enemies
void GenerateTraps()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Difficulty; i++)
    {
        int TotTraps = (Difficulty * 1.5);

        for (TotTraps; TotTraps == 0; TotTraps--)
        {
            int x = rand() % (MAPWidth - 1);
            int y = rand() % (MAPHeight - 1);

            if (Grid[y][x] == '.')
            {
                Grid[y][x] = 'T';
            }
            else
            {
                GenerateTraps();
            }
        }
    }
}

void GenerateTreasure()
{
    int x = rand() % MAPWidth;
    int y = rand() % MAPHeight;
    /*
    Randomly selects spawn location
    uses tmp variables to overwrite
    that grid location.
    */
    if (Grid[y][x] == '.')
    {
        Grid[y][x] = 'X';
    }
    else
    {
        GenerateTreasure();
    }

    TPosX = x;
    TPosY = y;
}
};

//PLAYER CLASS
class PLAYER : public MAP
{
public:

int Health = (Difficulty * 1.5);
int PPosX;
int PPosY;

char Direction; //Use cin to get user input after map is updated, used in switch case to move player.

void GenerateSpawn()
{
    int x = rand() % (MAPWidth - 1);
    int y = rand() % (MAPHeight - 1);

    /*
    Randomly selects spawn location
    uses tmp variables to overwrite
    that grid location.
    */

    Grid[y][x] = 'P';

    PPosX = x;
    PPosY = y;
}

void AllowMove(int y, int x)
{
    if (Grid[y][x] == '.')
    {
        Grid[y][x] = '@';
    }
    else if (Grid[y][x] == 'X')
    {
        //GameWin();
    }
    else if (Grid[y][x] == '#')
    {
        //DamagePlayer();
    }
    else {}

}

void MovePlayer()
{
    switch (Direction)
    {
    case 'w':
    {
        int x = PPosX;
        int y = (PPosY + 1);

        void AllowMove(int y, int x);
    }
    break;

    case 'a':
    {
        int x = (PPosX - 1);
        int y = PPosY;

        void AllowMove(int y, int x);
    }
    break;
    case 's':
    {
        int x = (PPosX);
        int y = PPosY;

        void AllowMove(int y, int x);
    }
    break;
    case 'd':
    {
        int x = (PPosX + 1);
        int y = PPosY;

        void AllowMove(int y, int x);
    }
    break;

    default:
        cout << "invalid character, try again." << endl;
        Sleep(5000);
        //Call function to retry
    }
}
};

//#########    End    #########

//Main Function
int main() {

srand(time(NULL)); //Used to seed rand() values.

SetConsoleTitle(TEXT("Dungeon Crawler"));

//Objects
MAP Map;
PLAYER Player;

Map.InitGrid();

Player.GenerateSpawn();

//Map.GenerateTreasure();
//Map.GenerateEnemies();
//Map.GenerateTraps();

Map.PrintMap();

cout << endl;

}
```

However, when I run these, I get the following image:

[image: this.]

I've attempted debugging in visual studio using breakpoints and at some point it does set the grid value to `'P'` but I couldn't find where I gets `'reset'` for lack of a better term.

Comment: Is `Grid` a global or a member variable?  It looks like you are calling member functions but the code you've shown is free functions.  It would be best to put together a short complete example and post the actual code with the issue.

Comment: Well, you call `GenerateSpawn()` from `Player` not from `Map` (if `Map` actually has a `GenerateSpawn()` member function). So, you actually init `Map` and then print it.

Comment: Fixed it, I was trying to print `Grid` that had been edited, however it was a separate `Grid` that players inherited, moved `Grid` to global variables and fixed it.

Comment: Can you possibly find a few more details and put it in an answer and accept it so everyone can see how you fixed it and they don't need to look at it when scrolling through the questions?

Answer (score 0):

`char Grid[MAPHeight][MAPWidth];` needs to be moved outside of the class as a global variable. Currently as the `PLAYER` class inherits from the `MAPS` class, when `GenerateSpawn()` edits the `Grid` that is created specific to the object linked to `PLAYER`.

When it is a global variable, it is separate, then when edited by `GenerateSpawn()` and called by `void PrintMap()` they both use the same `Grid`.

That way when it is printed to console it correctly prints out the map.

Answered my own question in case someone else stumbles upon this.